# compile QT statically

Tags: qt5

I want to compile QT statically , I did the following steps:

1)configure -static -debug -opensource

2)nmake sub-src but in this step I have some errors like

D:\qt\bin\rcc.exe -name mimetypes D:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1\
qtbase\src\corelib\mimetypes\mimetypes.qrc -o .rcc\debug_static\qrc_mimetypes.cp
p
'D:\qt\bin\rcc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'D:\qt\bin\rcc.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to compile Qt 5.x, you may need to install some libraries (depends of the modules you want to compile) :

- **ActivePerl** (** needed, as it is used to configure **qtsdk**)
- Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1
- Microsoft DirectX SDK
- Python
- ICU
- ...

If you plan to use a library (like Assimp for example) which internally use the same libraries (like zlib), you may have to overwrite these libraries, located in the **qtbase\src\3rdparty** sub-directories, with their latest versions.

Edit the file **configure.bat**, located in the **qtbase** directory, and comment out the line 45 :
`::if not exist %QTSRC%\.gitignore goto sconf`

Edit the file **qmake.conf**, located in **qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010** (if you're using Visual Studio 2010) or in **qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012** (if you're using Visual Studio 2012) :

- line 9 : `CONFIG                  += incremental flat precompile_header autogen_precompile_source debug_and_release debug_and_release_target`
- line 23 : `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT`
- line 24 : `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi`
- line 25 : `QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MTd`

Start the **Visual Studio command prompt** : Start > Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio 20XX > Visual Studio Tools.
Make sure that the path to **Perl.exe** is in the **PATH** environment variable : `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Perl\bin` (or `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Perl64\bin` if compiling for x64).

Go in the **qtbase** directory : `CD \Qt\5.0.1\qtbase`.

Configure Qt for compiling statically debug and release versions :

- `configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc2010 -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -static` (if you're using Visual Studio 2010)
- `configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc2012 -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -static` (if you're using Visual Studio 2012)

Examples and tests can be compiled later, if you need them.
If you plan to use **OpenGL**, add `-opengl desktop` to the command line, otherwise Qt will use by default OpenGL/ES which is targeted for mobile devices.
If your CPU is not multicore capable, remove the `-mp` option.

Go back in the parent directory : `CD ..`.

Configure again Qt : `configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc20`XX`-opengl desktop -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -static`
*(I'm not sure this step is needed, but as it takes just a few seconds...).*

Compile : `nmake`.

Another method for compiling is to use [jom](http://qt-project.org/wiki/jom) and specify the number of CPU cores to use : `C:\Qt\jom\jom.exe -j #NUMBER_OF_CORES#`.

You will find the compiled static libraries in the **qtbase\lib** folder and the files to include in the sub-directories of **qtbase\include**.
To use them, you will have to [use static run-time libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.100).aspx) (`/MT` or `/MTd`) in your Visual C++ project.